# Problem in real analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be convex and closed. Then for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$ there exists a unique point $y\in A$ such that for every $z \in A$ we have $$\|x-y\|= \min \|x-z\|,z \in A.$$

Comment: What about it? What's the question? What have you done to try to answer the question? Or was this an exercise for me?

Comment: There obviously is at least one, due to Weierstrass theorem. It is unique because, if there were two, then we'd have an isosceles triangle $ABC$, with base $AC$ and a point $D\in AC,\ D\ne A,\ D\ne C$ such that $BC\ge AB$. Which is impossible.